# Exit code 132 at librariers Keras and Tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

Iam using PyCharm on Ubuntu was trying to do some simple training, but cant import keras or tensorflow.

```
import keras
import tensorflow
```

Just these simple imports nothing else, and i get the following message when I run the code.

```
Process finished with exit code 132 (interrupted by signal 4: SIGILL)
```

I am new at linux, so any elaborate help would be useful,
Thanks.

Comment: which version of tensorflow and which python? Did you try with only `import tensorflow` since `keras` is part of `tensorflow`?

Comment: Tried to just import tensorflow. Python 3.8 and tensorflow 2.2.0

Comment: i have the same issue with python 3.7.9 and tensorflow 2.3.0